# Support for SOUTHBOUND in LoRaWAN

Tags: iot, fiware-orion, lorawan

As per my understanding of the code there is no SOUTHBOUND supported in LoRaWAN. (Sending measures from Orion to LoRaWAN)

Please confirm my above understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I've got no knowledge of fiware-orion but LoRaWAN supports uplink (towards the gatway) and downlink (from the gateway).

This websites seems to show interactions between end-node and the orion stuff.
[fiware-lorawan](https://fiware-lorawan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
[image]